# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on API call

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

On some devices, like a Samsung phone, sometimes when I am trying to http.post in my Ionic 2 application while the phone is asleep i get this error and the call is unsuccesful, what can be the reason behind this?
On other devices like Xiaomi phone everything works great.

Comment: It could be that the phone's asleep..  You might want to look into webworkers, that's the proper way to handle stuff while browser has not got focus / control.

Comment: sorry i should have mention that i am talking about application